# condition check - sparse data

Tags: r, string, conditional-statements

I wanted to check a condition that if a col is == 'value' - then if from a list of columns , is any column == 'value2'

```
# create dummy data set
pb=c('1','0','0','0','0','1','Not_ans','1','0','Not_ans')
qa=c('1','1','0','0','1','0','Not_ans','1','Not_ans','Not_ans')
#zy=c('1','Not_ans','0','1','Not_ans','0','1','1','1','Not_ans')

#sub questions for pb
pb.abr=c('1','0','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','0')
pb.ras=c('0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0')
pb.sfg=c('1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0')

#sub questions for qa
qa.fgs=c('1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0')
qa.sdf=c('0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')
qa.tyu=c('0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0')

df=data.frame(pb,qa,pb.abr,pb.ras,pb.sfg,qa.fgs,qa.sdf,qa.tyu)
df

        pb      qa     pb.abr pb.ras pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
1        1       1      1      0      1      1      0      0
2        0       1      0      0      0      0      1      0
3        0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4        0       0      0      0      0      0      0      0
5        0       1      0      1      0      0      0      1
6        1       0      1      0      0      0      0      0
7  Not_ans Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
8        1       1      1      1      1      1      0      1
9        0 Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
10 Not_ans Not_ans      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

in the above data set - what i want to check is if column 'pb' is 0 , then if any columns pb.abr OR pb.ras OR pb.sfg == 1

```
subset_df=subset(df,(pb==0) & ((pb.abr==1) | (pb.ras==1)|(pb.sfg==1)))
```

challenge is i have 100s of columns what have pb.xxx format and manually writing all columns in subset is not a feasible solution. How do i check the above with a logic which uses `contains("pb.")` and check across columns with an `OR` condition between the columns and in the end provide the data frame?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Edited and updated. I expect a data frame after the subset based on the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(pb == 0) %>%
  filter_at(vars(matches("pb\\.")), any_vars(.  == 1))

#  pb qa pb.abr pb.ras pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
#1  0  1      0      1      0      0      0      1
```

---

Or in base R

```
df[df$pb == 0 & rowSums(df[grep("pb\\.", names(df))] == 1) > 0, ]

#  pb qa pb.abr pb.ras pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
#5  0  1      0      1      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Ronak - just to check if incase of OR - condition was 'AND' say the subset was `subset_df=subset(df,(pb==1) & (pb.abr==0) & (pb.ras==0) & (pb.sfg==0))` what would the solution be?

Comment: @Pb89 Use `all_vars` in that case, `df %>%
  filter(pb == 1) %>%
  filter_at(vars(matches("pb\\.")), all_vars(.  == 0))`

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

```
dont' forget to set StringsAsFactors to FALSE!
df=data.frame(pb,qa,pb.abr,pb.ras,pb.sfg,qa.fgs,qa.sdf,qa.tyu, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**code**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  #set all columns starting with 'pb.' to numeric
  mutate_at( vars( starts_with("pb.") ), funs( as.numeric ) ) %>%
  #first filter
  filter( pb == "0" ) %>%
  #second filter
  filter( rowSums( .[, grep("pb\\.", names(df))]) > 0 )
```

**output**

> ```
>   pb qa pb.abr pb.ras pb.sfg qa.fgs qa.sdf qa.tyu
> 1  0  1      0      1      0      0      0      1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As a one liner:

```
filter(df,pb==0 & rowSums(z[,grepl("pb\\.",names(z))])>0)
```